# Best / Minimal settings for ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, video-conversion

I'm trying to get the best and most basic options to convert my avi video to webm. The audio is not a issue. It's the video. Currently, I've tried `ffmpeg -i input.avi output.webm`. This seems to only render the audio, as I get no video, but only audio. I've tried `ffmpeg -i input.avi -crf 5 output.webm` this does the same thing. Renders the audio, but no video. I've also increased and decreased the crf number.

When I do `ffmpeg -i input.avi output.mp4` it outputs perfectly fine with really good quality. Almost identical from the source. Though if I was to take that mp4 and convert it to a webm with similar commands as stated above, it renders both audio and video, but the video bitrate is absolutely atrocious and is *very* pixelated compared to the avi or mp4.

So my question is: How can I make it render my avi to webm with video and am able to adjust the bit rate of the output?

Comment: Show the console output for your first command.

Comment: I figured it out, I had to set the codec to libvpx (webm) and use `b:v` to set the bitrate.

Comment: The default codec for WebM is libvpx unless yours is an old version of ffmpeg.

Comment: Comments are transient, and even if they remain, people may not notice that you no longer need a solution.  Please consider posting an answer, which would be helpful to others with a similar problem.  Accepting your own answer will indicate that the problem has been solved.

Comment: @Mulvya I have ffmpeg 3.1.5, just checked. When I said `set`, I meant specify.